# I want to remove specific property from list not whole elements

Tags: list, c#-4.0

Kindly help here. Below is my class:

```
public class UserGroup : Result
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

I have list type of UserGroup class and I am trying to remove UserId and GroupId property from the list whenever I am getting 0 value for both property, however it removing whole particular class elements along with result class property.I want error tag in output it should not remove. Below is my output :

```
<EditGroupMembershipResult>
            <UserGroup>
                <Error>
                    <string>User does not exist</string>
                    <string>User group does not exist</string>
                </Error>
                <UserId>0</UserId>
                <GroupId>0</GroupId>
            </UserGroup>
        </EditGroupMembershipResult>
```

Comment: "I want error tag in output it should not remove" - it's not at all clear to me what you mean by that... what you've shown is XML, not a list... and you haven't shown the code that does the wrong thing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem ?

Comment: This is one of the my web service function and I am calling this web service from postman that is the reason I am getting list as xml format in output. When I am trying to remove <UserId>0</UserId> from list it is removeing <Error><string>User does not exist</string><string>User group does not exist</string></Error>. For reference I upload image on : https://www.screencast.com/t/GdAPW7APxull

Answer (score 1):

you can use ToArray() on your list to Remove a specific Item(s):

```
  List<UserGroup > userGroups = new List<UserGroup >();
    //Add Item to your List Here.
    foreach (string item in userGroups.ToArray())
    {
        if (item == "UserId" || item == "GroupId")
          {
            userGroups.Remove(item);
          }
    }
```

Comment: Here what you mean by "strings.Remove(item);" you will not get any strings.remove() method :(

Comment: @Nimeshkhatri, Good Point! I just edited the code. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: It showing compile time error. for reference see : https://www.screencast.com/t/6nOnJQzUP6